# Apply each after appending

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such call in my JS file:

```
$('.selector').each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > 36) {}
});
```

It works fine when using standard HTTP request but I have also some AJAX calls that load extra data using `append` method for example this way:

```
$('#something').append(result.data);
```

In data I receive via AJAX I also have `.selector` but this `$('.selector').each(function () {` is not run for those results. How can I make to jQuery to run it also on appended results?

Comment: Check the binding function. This will help for elements that are not yet present.

Comment: after appending the data into DOM, jquery should be able read the elements and manage it.

Comment: Please see this example : https://jsfiddle.net/arshadmuhammed/q11Lb2q2/ . Everything is working fine even after appending the data with the class used in `.each`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say put this in the function:

```
function loopOver(){
   $('.selector').each(function () {
      if ($(this).height() > 36) {

      }
  });
}
```

now when you do this just call this function:

```
 $('#something').append(result.data);
 loopOver(); // <------here
```

Comment: This is what I did just before your answer, this is what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

User [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) instead of append.

```
$(result.data).appendTo($('#something')).each(function () {...}});
```

Comment: the selector or element which is passed inside `appendTo` has to be physically present in DOM. in this case it is not